# slash at the start of a mvc parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I use this route in my controller

```
[HttpGet("Check/{*code}")]
```

this work in almost all cases, but this does't work with slash at the start in parameter, like "**/1HCZ0hVPloeftdvDHgGNg==**" this generate next url

```
api/check//1HCZ0hVPloeftdvDHgGNg==
```

so, the controller read "1HCZ0hVPloeftdvDHgGNg==" and crash decrypt code.

How solve this?

Comment: What is your .net core version? How did you request this url? I made a test by sending this request `https://localhost:44381/check//1HCZ0hVPloeftdvDHgGNg==`, it works correctly to get `/1HCZ0hVPloeftdvDHgGNg==` for `code`. Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say version of ASP.NET you're using but I think

```
using System.Web.HttpUtility;
string queryString = UrlEncode("/1HCZ0hVPloeftdvDHgGNg==");
```

should work for you.  It will convert the slash (and any other weird characters) to Uri-safe values.  In your case, `queryString = "%2f1HCZ0hVPloeftdvDHgGNg%3d%3d"`

On the other end, you will need to use UrlDecode to get it back to the original string also.

Function documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netcore-2.2#System_Web_HttpUtility_UrlEncode_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_).

Comment: still doesn't recognize / only if this found in a start of string

Comment: Apologies, missed the fact you wanted to do it only via routing.  When I encode then send to the controller that way I get a double-escape error.  So, it seems like even if you encode the slash before sending, something in the pipeline is decoding it before it tries to decipher the route.  There's some discussion of this behavior on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2696)